# Understanding finding the z-score with given proportion?

Tags: statistics

I am asked to find the z-score of the proportion .05 to +∞

I look the z-table to find the associated z-score with the value .05. This part I understand I found it to be: -1.64 but then what's the part about +∞ I don't understand what this means or how I am to apply it once I find the associated z-score.

Another problem is similar it asks to find the associated z-score with p=.33 to -∞

I found the z-score to be z=-0.44 but then again where does the -∞ factor into all this?

Thank you

Comment: I think there is some confusion here between z-scores and probabilities and between 0.05 and 0.005.

Answer (score 1):

A z-score is a single value: It seems you are being asked to find probabilities
based on z-scores, assuming a standard normal distribution.

The number $c$ on the z-scale such that $P(Z > c) = 0.05 = 5\%.$ is $c = 1.645.$
That is, $P(1.645 < Z < \infty) = P(Z > 1.645) = 0.05,$ where $Z$ is a random variable with the standard normal distribution.

Also, $P(Z < -1.645) = 0.05$ and $P(-1.645 < Z < 1.645) = 0.90.$

The figure below shows the standard normal density curve. The total area beneath a density cure is $1$ or 100%. In each 'tail' of
the distribution, outside the vertical red lines, there is area 5% representing
probability $0.05.$ Between the two red lines there is probability $0.9.$

[image]

By contrast, $P(-2.576 < Z < \infty) = 1 - P(Z < -2.576) = 1 - .005 = .995.$ The area to the right of the vertical orange line is 99.5%. The tiny area to the left of the line is $\frac 1 2 \% = 0.005.$

[image]

Finally, the number $a$ such that $P(a < Z < \infty) = P(Z > a) = 0.33,$ is
$a = 0.4399.$

In the figure below 33% of the probability under the curve lies to the
right of the purple line and 67% lies to the left of it.

[image]

*Notes:* (a) In all of these computations the z-values (such as $a, c$) are found
in the *margins* of a printed table of standard normal probabilities, and
the probabilities (such as $.0500, 0.0050, and 0.570$) are found in the *body* of the table. (b) There must be some examples explaining how to use printed
standard normal tables in your textbook. Please go through those examples
carefully--along with the ones I have provided above. (c) You can't make
curves as accurate as mine by hand, but in working problems on normal probabilities, it is a good idea to make a rough sketch of the normal curve, shading in the area that matches the desired probability. That can keep you
from getting confused and making huge errors.